# Undefined Property and PHP Fatal Error: Allowed memory exhausted when querying mssql from php through unixODBC/FreeTDS

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, alias, freetds

After upgrading php from version 5.2.10 to 5.3.3 I am getting a very strange set of errors when using odbc queries that works fine in 5.2.10.

I get a lot of *Undefined Property: stdClass::$username* finally ending in a *Memory Exhaust Allowed* error when I run queries like the following:

```
    $conn = odbc_connect("dsn", "user", "pw") or die(odbc_error_msg()); 

    $query = "select usr_n as username from usr";
    $rs = odbc_exec($conn,$query);

    while ($rows = odbc_fetch_object($rs)) {
        echo "$rows->username";
        }
    odbc_free_result($rs);
    odbc_close($conn);
```

the strange part is that if I run this code without the 'username' alias and use the table name as shown in the query underneath, it works fine:

```
    $conn = odbc_connect("dsn", "user", "pw") or die(odbc_error_msg()); 

    $query = "select usr_n from usr";
    $rs = odbc_exec($conn,$query);

    while ($rows = odbc_fetch_object($rs)) {
        echo "$rows->usr_n";
        }
    odbc_free_result($rs);
    odbc_close($conn);
```

also if I use alias with a count(*) statement it works fine, but as soon as I replace a tablename with an alias it all goes wrong.

I tried the query in iSQL with the alias, and it works like it is supposed to, so the unixODBC and FreeTDS is working.

I have searched through all the material I could find both here and google, but havent got any answer to why this is happening.

Appreciate it if anyone here has an idea to what is going on here, as it seems to me to have something to do with aliases and I use aliases a lot.

BTW: Upgrading php is sadly not an option for me.

Comment: Would it be feasible for you to use `odbc_fetch_array()` instead of `odbc_fetch_object`? And if so, does that fix your problem?

Comment: I only have two more suggestions: 1) Use PDO instead of odbc_* functions and 2) enable ODBC logging and see if there are any clues in the log.

Comment: I have tried to use array, row and object and they all return the same error. The only difference is the "Undefined Property: stdClass::$username" part, which is changing depending on type of resulting dataset.

Comment: I will try PDO and see what happens. BTW, is there any way/tool to see live memory usage for the php script as I run it?

Comment: [memory_get_peak_usage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php) and related functions might be of interest to you.

Comment: Thanks Benny, I will try your suggestions and give a feedback on the development of this issue.

Comment: I found a workaround to the problem. I can cast the value before assigning it to an alias. ie. cast(usr_n as varchar(255)) as username.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was accented characters (spanish). I solved this adding `Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI` to every field with this chars on every SELECT.